OneTimeSetUp: System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString') -In Memory Database
I'm trying to set up an automated testing framework using NUnit and after I decided that going through the extreme pain of attempting to use Moq and specifically to set up some of the Moq behaviour handling (Async behaviour was the first big one and then Auto-Incrementing behaviour got me to quit trying to make it work and look for something else) was just not worth it long-term I eventually stumbled on using an In-Memory Database as one of the ways the data handling of the test scenario can be done, since from what I could understand it basically copies the structure and everything of the real DB with none of the data before then automatically dumping itself after the test scenario's ran its course
Sounded pretty much exactly like how I wanted my test scenarios to behave in regards to data handling
So, as I was doing the setup for that thing by making sense of and stringing together what I could find out about the process online, I eventually ended up getting the error message in the title when attempting to run my test case
I've tried searching around for similar problems to mine but everything besides one SO thread was about something too different to really be of much help and that one thread which was also about an In-Memory DB with a similar issue as in the title turned out to have a problem entirely different from mine with their own setup of the thing
I'm stumped on how to deal with this, honestly
Here is what the onetime setup function roughly looks like in the test scenario class
private ServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

[OneTimeSetUp]
public void OneTimeSetUp()
{
    #region Service and DB setup
    var services = new ServiceCollection();

    //Instantiating the IConfiguration
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddInMemoryCollection()
        .Build();

    //Mocking IWebHostEnvironment
    var envMock = new Mock<IWebHostEnvironment>() { CallBase = true };
    envMock.Setup(m => m.EnvironmentName).Returns("Development");
    envMock.Setup(m => m.ApplicationName).Returns("Web Platform");

    //Instantiating Startup with the mock web environment and the instantiated IConfiguration
    var startup = new Startup(configuration, envMock.Object);
    startup.ConfigureServices(services);

    //Overriding the DbContext registration to use an in-memory database for testing
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("TestDb_Sc1"));

    _serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    #endregion

    //Seeding initial data
    using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
    {
        var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
        var dbContext = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

        var buyerTestData = new Buyer(){/*data*/};
        var topicTestData = new Topic(){/*data*/};


        dbContext.Buyers.Add(testBuyer);
        dbContext.Topics.Add(testTopic);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}

Here is what the test case function in the test scenario looks like
[Test]
public async Task AdminAddsMessageToTopic()
{
    //Arrange
    using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
    {
        var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
        BuyerLogic manager = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<BuyerLogic>();
        var dbContext = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

        var messagePostModel = new MessagePostModel(){/*data*/};

        //Creating ClaimsPrincipal for the test case
        var claims = new[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "userIdString"),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "userEmail")
        };
        ClaimsPrincipal user = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "mock"));

        Uri referrer = new Uri("https://fakelink.com/fakepage");

        // Act
        Message addedMessage = await manager.AddMessage(messagePostModel, user, referrer);

        // Asserts
    }
}

Here is what the configuration function looks like in the Startup class
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHostedService<TestData>();
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Database"));
        options.UseOpenIddict();
    });
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = Claims.Name;
        options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = Claims.Subject;
        options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = Claims.Role;
        options.Password = new PasswordOptions()
        {
            //Options data
        };

    });

Here is what the connection strings looks like in my appsettings.json file
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "Database": "Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;initial catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True"
},

Any ideas what the issue is? Or why the In-Memory DB's even trying to get into the connection strings? Because my understading was that the In-Memory Database wasn't supposed to interact with the real DB beyond the initial copying of its structure

Are you using an In-Memory DB provider? SQLExpress is not in-memory, or at least I believe it is not. If you are attempting to use SQLExpress and call a method that says 'In-Memory', that does not make the provider an in-memory provider.

Don't use in-memory, EF discourage it themselves.

@Matthew I'm not entirely sure what this In-Memory DB provider is, so I'm probably not using it. Is that something that needs to be set up in the Startup's Configuration function? Or a package I need to install?

@GertArnold Why? EF doesn't mesh well with it? I'm fine with defaulting to using a dedicated real test DB but In-Memory DB looked like it achieved more or less what I'm looking for with what I'm trying to set up without the need for an actual real test DB

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

@GertArnold Cheers mate, had a look through this and another thing I found talking about the topic and the broad consensus seems to be just using a real DB for testing which is fair enough. In-Memory was just the last thing I wanted to try out before defaulting to that option
